# Open a pandas dataframe in an interactive widget, NOT in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've been looking for that desperately. I don't like jupyter notebooks (for my own personal reasons). Is there a way to open/displays a pandas dataframe in some sort of small, interactive widget/spreadsheet? Something that could be called from ipython and that would look like sqlitebrowser's interface:

[image]

It would be really useful for data inspection. Of course I could dump the data frame to a csv file and open it with any spreadsheet program, but someone must have developed a simpler approach?

Comment: If you are using pycharm there is a view as table option

Comment: I'd like that in ipython, IDE-independent. The point is to interact with the dataframe, and display it from time to time. I could dump the dataframe into a csv and open it with a spreadsheet software, but that's not what I want here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found something that seems to answer my expectations:

It's a ncurse interface to view tables. It has Vim key bindings (perfect), and the tables can be scrolled vertically and horizontally. It can be called from ipython.

However, it doesn't support pandas dataframe at the moment, but a PR is available:

https://github.com/TabViewer/tabview/pull/116

I'm open to other suggestions but it will do the trick for now.